# Ошибка: invalid conversion 'from' int to 'int(*)()'

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Всем добра.

Возникает ошибка при компиляции: "invalid conversion from `int` to `int(*)()` [-fpermissive]",при нажатии кнопки  вызова функции  добавления строки  в БД SQLite через модел/представление.

```
void CommonWindow::addRowClicked() 
{
    int a = 1;
    m_model->insertRows(m_model->rowCount(QModelIndex()), a, QModelIndex());
}
```

Проблема с `m_model->rowCount(QModelIndex())`

```
int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &index) const 
{
   QSqlQuery query(QString("SELECT count(*) FROM %1").arg(dBName));
   int rowsNumber = query.value(0).toInt();
   return rowsNumber;
}
```

вот сама функция вставки строки:

```
bool TableModel::insertRows(int rowCount(), int rows , const QModelIndex &parent)
{
  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
  {
     int rows=1;
     QSqlQuery query(QString("INSERT INTO %1 (depthHole, inclinationAngle, horizontalAngle, TVD, intensityInclAngle, intensityHorizontAngle, color, comment) DEFAULT VALUES").arg(dBName));
  }
  endInsertRows();
  return true;
}
```

вот только я не совсем понимаю: Ошибка "conversion from int to int(*)()" это получается из int в int указалтель. Но я нигде не вижу указателя. Может быть конечно все таки лыжи едут, а дело во мне...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int(*)()` - это не просто указатель, а указатель на функцию. Вы вызываете метод `insertRows` так:

```
                    /*     Это int                */
m_model->insertRows(m_model->rowCount(QModelIndex()), a, QModelIndex());
```

А объявили эту функцию так:

```
                           /* Это int(*)()*/
bool TableModel::insertRows(int rowCount(), int rows , const QModelIndex &parent)
```

Теперь видите ошибку?

---

UPD.

Во-первых, вы не переопределили виртуальную функцию, а написали новую. Чтобы компилятор проверял, действительно ли виртуальная функция переопределена, добавьте в h-файле после объявления функции слово `override`:

```
virtual bool insertRows(int rowCount, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent) override;
```

Во-вторых, в определении функции не может быть вызова другой функции. Количество строк в таблице вы вычисляете при вызове и передаёте с первым аргументом и делаете это правильно.

---

UPD2.

Давайте разберёмся. Вот ваш вызов функции:

```
m_model->insertRows(m_model->rowCount(QModelIndex()), a, QModelIndex());
```

здесь эта конструкция

```
m_model->rowCount(QModelIndex())
```

вычисляет количество строк в модели. Полученное число типа `int` передаётся как параметр в функцию `insertRows`. Стало быть, функция `insertRows` должна это число типа `int` принять. Зачем тогда вы пытаетесь "вызвать" функцию в определении функции `insertRows`? У вас как раз и получился не вызов, а объявление указателя на функцию. Сделайте так:

```
bool TableModel::insertRows(int rowCount, int rows , const QModelIndex &parent)
```

и всё заработает.

Comment: Просто впервые столкнулся с данной проблемой. получается если в качестве аргумента фунеции я указывая другую  функцую, то в функцию передается указатель на функцию. А подскажите тогда как надо ее объявить,чтобы эта функция rowCount была int, а не int(*)(). Функция 'insertRows(int rowCount(), int rows , const QModelIndex &parent)' это же '[virtual] bool QAbstractItemModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())'

Comment: но чтобы добавить строку в конец, я счичаю количество строк через rowCount(). а если не через нее, то что-то никак я не соображу тогда как передать количтво строк в БД.

Comment: @Юра Л: У вас в коде уже есть несколько параметров типа `int`, которые объявлены правильно. И вы при этом в упор не видите, в чем проблема с объявлением `int rowCount()`? Как такое возможно?

Comment: @Abyx, согласен, `virtual` здесь избыточный. Но я намеренно его здесь оставил.

Comment: @maestro, я не свовсем понял в вышем примере с переопределением функции стоит переменная int rowCount, а не функция int rowCount(). Так правильно? если да,  то как вы сказали вначале   потом при вызове функции в качестве одного из аргументов как здесь: `m_model->insertRows(m_model->rowCount(QModelIndex()), a, QModelIndex())` будет правильно, главное чтобы возращаемы тип был тот же int. и поэтому мне и AnT на нее и указывает?

Comment: большое спасибо, @maestro, все сделал как вы сказали и получилось. теперь после вашего  UPD2 все стало на свои места в моей голове.